# Creating exactly N threads with Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I know that i can execute tasks asynchronously with `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_get_global_queue`.

But how many threads dispatch_async create?
What should i do to execute exactly N (no more, no less) threads with GCD, and performe some tasks on them? After execution of task i need to add new task in released thread, maybe in complitation block of previous task.

Or maybe i can control the count of threds with `NSOperationQueue`?
I know that it has property `maxConcurrentOperationCount`, but it control only maximum limit of tasks. So, Can I be sure that NSOperationQueue creates no less than 8 threads, in case when i set maxConcurrentOperationCount = 8 and add 12 operations to the `NSOperationQueue`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: why? the reason of using GCD is to save save us from finding optimal thread count. If you want exactly N threads, then create them yourself using NSThread

Comment: there is no reason in practice, it is just for research.

Comment: `maxConcurrentOperationCount` is just a maximum. It could create fewer. If you need precise control over the number of threads, then you'll have to manage them yourself.

Comment: @xlc The reason this would be useful is that if your apps dispatches too many operations, you tie up the system, end up blocking the main queue in the process. It strikes me as a fairly glaring omission in GCD and why I now generally use operation queues. This omission defeats many of the benefits of GCD for massively parallel operations.

Comment: @Rob main queue won't get blocked unless you add operations into main queue, which you shouldn't if you want concurrent operations. and `NSOperationQueue` is based on GCD.

Comment: @xlc - I know it defies intuition, but [WWDC 2012 - iOS App Performance: Responsiveness](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=235) warns of the risks of too many concurrent GCD tasks in "GCD Gotchas", suggesting serial dispatch queue, concurrent operation queue, or dispatch IO as remedies. [Asynchronous Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712) illustrates the point nicely. You absolutely can freeze your app if you dispatch too many tasks to background concurrent dispatch queue. I have seen this first hand and swapping in operation queue solved it.

Comment: @xlc To be more precise, it doesn't block the main queue, but it can consume all of the threads, effectively freezing your app in certain situations. If GCD had some ability to constrain how many worker threads it consumed, it would be very useful.

Comment: @Rob i know that in osx there is a limit of maximum 64 worker threads, not sure about ios. also GCD will only spawn new threads if CPU is not fully utilized (thats whole poiont of using GCD). i agree it is possible to create have 64 busy worker threads using GCD but it is unlikely to happen if you use it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into [NSThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's the way to go if you need fine grain control over exactly the number of threads you want to have running.

Answer (score 4):

Subclass [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) for the tasks you want to do and put them into an [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). You can set the number of concurrent operations on the queue.

```
NSOperationQueue *q = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
q. maxConcurrentOperationCount = N;
```

Comment: But the property called maxConcurrentOperationCount, and i think that it set only maximum but not minimum number of threads, am i right?

Comment: That's right. However, if you set the max to be 6 and only add 5 operations surely it's better not to create that last unused thread until you need it?

Comment: @deanWombourne +1 I agree that using `NSOperationQueue` is a great way to set the max (but not the min). But you suggest you need to subclass `NSOperation`, but obviously that's not necessary (90-95% of the time, when I'm using operation queues, I just do `addOperationWithBlock` and don't create my own operations at all. And when I need to create operations (such as to control `dependencies`), I often use `NSOperationBlock` or the like. Certainly you can subclass, if your app call for that, but frequently that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Queue concept is different from thread. Go through NSThread class. Since NSOperation uses GCD you can't set thread from here. You can merge the NSThread and NSOperation creating and passing different threads. 
 But why would you do that? more thread doesn't mean more speed, usually is the opposite with a lot of concern about memory, locking, concurrency etc. 
You should have a very specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the max count of threads when using gcd, you can make use of `DispatchSemaphore`. Firstly, create a `semaphore` with the max count, secondly at the beginning of a task, `semaphore.wait()`, finally at the end of a task, `semaphore.signal()`.